# Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-Classic

Tags: emacs

I am using GNU emacs 23.1.1 on Fedora 12

I have this in my .emacs file

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-Classic))
```

And I get the following error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-Classic
```

I have all the libraries in my /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp directory

```
color-theme.el
color-theme-example.el
color-theme-library.el
themes/
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Classic should be classic?

Comment: I tried it. "Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-classic." Also I did M-X and selected classic by doing this color-theme-select. And scrolling down to classic and clicking it. I still got the same answer. Any other help would be most helpful.

Comment: I don't have an Emacs 23.1 I can use right now. If no-one else answers I'll try again later when it is available.

Comment: Hmm, I installed this package into ~/emacs/ on Windows and tried your above code (with Classic changed to classic), and it worked without any problems.

Comment: Hello, seems very strange. I am using Fedora 12 which I have just installed. And I copied the theme's *.el to the site-lisp directory, as above. However, everything worked fine on Fedora 11. I have my code changed to classic as well. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry I don't use Fedora at the moment. I tested this on Microsoft Windows since that is the only 23.1 Emacs I have running anywhere. Does everything else work?

Comment: I downloaded the color-theme-6.6.0.zip file from http://nongnu.askapache.com/color-theme/, unzipped it, ran the make file and copied the themes directory and *.elc to /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp, ran your test code and got the void definition error.  Then I changed "Classic" to "classic" and my Emacs instance did all sorts of color goodness things so I conclude from all that that capitalization is in fact the issue.

Comment: I downloaded the color-theme-6.6.0 and ran the makefile and followed in the instructions. However, I did get this "error: Required feature `color-theme-autoload' was not provided". However, despite this I still managed to get my color themes working ok.