# How to fix "Symbol's function definition is void" while loading up a color theme in emacs24?

Tags: emacs, color-scheme

When I load my `.emacs`, although the color theme, twilight, loads up fine, but it shows me this error message:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-twilight
```

In my `.emacs` I have put the following lines to add the color theme:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(setq color-theme-is-global t)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-twilight)
```

The `color-theme-twilight.el` file lives in `~/.emacs.d/themes/`

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778469/symbols-function-definition-is-void-color-theme-classic) question. But the solution there is a correction to a typo. But I am not making that typo. I am on emacs24. What is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Solved the problem. Removed all the lines :

```
(require 'color-theme)
(setq color-theme-is-global t)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-twilight)
```

And just added:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/themes/color-theme-twilight.el")
```

The problem was the last line:

```
(color-theme-twilight)
```

Other three lines are not required at all. Not sure if this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: I don't remember now, but I think this might have been the file not being on my `load-path`. There's more info [here](https://superuser.com/a/835663/231401) about when this sort of an error comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emacs 24, I think you could change the 4 lines you include by this single line:

```
(load-theme 'twilight t)
```

No extra requires; this use the emacs 24 theme approach.

If you are using a recent version of twilight, that should give you no error.

Comment: Try moving the .el file to a directory in your load path.  In fact, it would be simpler if you installed that theme via package-install.

Answer (score 0):

You say "The `color-theme-twilight.el` file lives in ~/.emacs.d/themes/." But I don't see where you load that file. Add `(require 'color-theme-twilight)` to your init file, and make sure `color-theme-twilight.el` is in your `load-path`.

Comment: Tried. Error message: `Cannot open load file: color-theme-twilight`

Comment: If you put a file named `color-them-twilight.el` in your `load-path`, and if you evaluate `(require 'color-theme-twilight)`, and if that file does `(provide 'color-theme-twilight)`, then the file will be loaded. But if the file does no `provide` then you need to use `load-library`, `load`, or `load-file` to load it, instead of `require`. If it has `provide`, but `provide` gives a different feature name than `color-theme-twilight`, then your `require` needs to use that feature name also. Do `C-h f` for each of the functions I've mentioned, and you will no doubt understand.